# Change Formik to react-hook-form v7

Tags: react-hook-form

I am refactoring a Formik form to react-hook-form v7. The Formik form has this structure:

```
<FormikProvider value={form}>
 <Form>
 <Field
    component={FighterInput}
    fighterAvailability={fighterAvailabilityStatus}
 />
 <StandardButton
  type="submit"
 >
 </StandardButton>
</Form>
</FormikProvider>
```

The FighterInput component is a component which has an input field and a function that renders a div based on fighter availability.

I need to get the typed in value character by character because a useEffect triggers other functions so I need to use react-hook-form watch or something else that let's me grab every character that is typed in to the {FighterInput} component, this is currently achieved with Formiks context values, but I need to do this in react-hook-form.

I've been able to get the value using watch with the following approach:

```
const fighter = watch('fighterInput');

<form>
      <input {...register("fighterInput")} />
</form>
```

But this is not using the {FighterInput} component. The {FighterInput} component accepts props and returns an an input field. It also has some functions that renders a div based on conditionals set in the useEffect in the main component where I want to use react-hook-form and import {FighterInput}

How can I transform the Formik form with the above structure to achieve the same thing using react-hook-form v7 and render the {FighterInput} component while being able to grab every character on-the-fly as it is being typed into the input of {FighterInput} ?

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="test"
  render={({
    field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
    fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty, error },
    formState,
  }) => (
    <FighterInput
      onChange={onChange} // send value to hook form
      checked={value}
      inputRef={ref}
      {...register("fighterInput")} // not working

    />
  )}
/>
```

In addition to being able to watch the input, I need to be able to access form values in my FighterInput component as well and wondering how I can do that, am I supposed to use react-hook-forms useFormContext or FormProvider?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, so I assume you've found a path forward by now. For other folks who might be coming here looking for some help, I wanted to share the following guide:

https://github.com/trussworks/formik-to-react-hook-form-migration-guide

Since there's different ways to use Formik and React Hook form (especially with different considerations depending on your component library), it may not solve all your needs, but I hope it at least provides a solid starting point!

There are some working linked examples in that guide which recommends using `useController` inside of your form component (or that's how we did it at least).

The Controller and register could be in conflict, however. In the linked examples, we're not using register for custom components, since useController implies that the rendered field is a controlled field